# Changing label positions in a R party plot (decision/regression trees)

Tags: r, plot, decision-tree, party

The `partykit` package give a nice representation of decision trees. The only problem I have with it is when labels are long and then they are overlapping. Is it possible to move those labels to prevent it (see the blue arrows on the picture below)?

```
library("rpart")
library("partykit")
rp <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data = kyphosis)
party_rp <- as.party(rp)

plot(party_rp)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default panel function for drawing the edge labels `edge_simple` implements a few justification strategies: Labels can either `"alternate"` across the edges, be `"decreasing"`, `"increasing"`, or `"equal"`. However, these justification strategies are just employed starting from a minimum label length of `justmin` which defaults to `Inf` (i.e., no justification). See `?edge_simple` for more details.

You wanted to see an example where justification is `"increasing"` and *always* applied (i.e., `justmin = 1`):

```
plot(party_rp,
  ep_args = list(justmin = 1, just = "increasing"))
```

[image: edge_simple]